# square root of $\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

> Find the square root of $\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}$.

Attempt:

I'm thinking of equating it to $a + bi$. And then finding the root. Is that right?

Comment: If you equate it to $a+ib$ then $b=0$, so what have you gained?

Comment: Oh my bad. So how do I go about it?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? Is $\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2}$ good enough?

Comment: Define ``find''. $\frac {\sqrt{2 + \sqrt 3}}2$ is good enough for me.

Comment: Use $ 2+ \sqrt 3 = \frac{(\sqrt3+1)^2}{2} $

Comment: The square root is  ( √6 + √2 ) / 4 but I don't know how to get that.

Comment: @user274246, I hope my answer below addresses your last comment.

Comment: $\frac{2+i2\sqrt{3}}{4}=e^{i \pi/3}$ whose root is $e^{i\pi/6}$

Answer (score 2):

For convenience we will work with $4(2+\sqrt3)$ to avoid fractions.

Let us search a solution of the form $a+b\sqrt3$, giving

$$(a+b\sqrt3)^2=a^2+3b^2+2ab\sqrt3=8+4\sqrt3.$$

By identifying $2ab$ and $4$, we have $b=\dfrac2a$ and

$$a^2+\frac{12}{a^2}+4\sqrt3=8+4\sqrt3.$$

By inspection (or resolution of a quadratic equation), $a^2=2$, so that

$$\left(\sqrt2+\frac2{\sqrt2}\sqrt3\right)^2=8+4\sqrt3,$$
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}4\right)^2=\frac{2+\sqrt3}4.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}$ is a positive number so it has a **real** square root.

Notice first that:
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2}$$
 so what you have to find is $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$. A technique is to try to find what are $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ where $2+\sqrt{3}=(a+b)^2$ so that $2+\sqrt{3}=|a+b|$.

You have $$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$$.

The technique in such cases is to try to get $a^2+b^2=2$ and $2ab=\sqrt{3}$.

Notice that $b=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2a}$

If you put it in $a^2+b^2=2$ you'll have an equation with one variable $a$.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, notice that:
$$\frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{2\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2}}{4},$$
where I've used [zezanjee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/213960)'s hint
$$2 + \sqrt{3} = \frac{(\sqrt{3} + 1)^2}{2}$$
in the comments.